# Running into problems deploying a multithreated application in aws

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, wsgi, python-multithreading

So I have been working on a Django application and everything seems to work fine in my developing environment but not on a cloud instance.

The application's server must do two things in parallel. I initially used a subprocess to execute some task while the main process keeps collecting data.

Everything works as expected offline but when I deploy the application onto AWS it just does one thing at a time.

I made sure I deployed it on an instance with multiple cores. I even went back to change the subprocess task and spawned a new thread instead but that did not seem to work either.

Also not sure if this could be the issue but running the subtask involves running a shell command that starts up a docker container.

Has anyone ran into a similar issue or got any suggestions about what could be causing this behavior?

Thanks.